# How can a parent component subscribe to child component's "formState.isDirty" in react-hook-form v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

My user case is that if an end user wants to move away from a particular screen, and if there are unsaved changes in this screen, then the app would warn user.

Now my child component (this particular screen to check dirty) is a form built on top of react-hook-form v6, which provides "formState.isDirty". My parent component is sitting on top of "react-router" to route to appropriate screens

One thing I tried is that in my parent component, take advantage of useState hook and pass callback to child:

`const [userDirty, setDirty] = useState(undefined)`

Then in my child component, I have this:

```
const methods = useForm() 
useEffect(() => {
    setDirty(methods.formState.isDirty)
}, )
```

It works only when end user-interaction-with-child-form has caused a re-render. But there are times end user made a change to the form and no re-render, then above code would not work since "useEffect" only runs at each re-render.
Here is an example when it does not work -- end user edits a text input:

```
<Form.Control  type="text"  name="customDisplayName"
                        defaultValue={xxx}
                        ref={register}  
>
```

I understand that one approach is to add an "onChange" handler to each input in my child component, and then "setDirty" there. But it is a complex form, which has many children input.

```
    <Form.Control  type="text"  name="customDisplayName"
                        defaultValue={xxx}
                        ref={register}  
                         onChange={()=>{
                          setDirty(true)
                        }}
>
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. API docs has this: (https://react-hook-form.com/v6/api/#formState)

If you want to subscribe to formState update at useEffect, **make sure that you place the entire formState in the optional array.**

So once I tweaked "useEffect" to below, it then works as expected

```
useEffect(() => {
    seteDirty(methods.formState.isDirty)
}, [methods.formState])
```